# How can I play Virtua Cop (Sega Saturn/MAME) with light guns on a modern display?

Tags: controllers, emulation, mame

I want to play Virtua Cop, with a light gun or "equivalent" (Wiimote would suffice). But using my old Sega Saturn is too difficult (old CD laser, no HDMI, etc). An emulator for the PC is preferable.

[image: Virtua Cop Sega Saturn]
(Image from [abandonwaredos.com](https://www.abandonwaredos.com/abandonware-game.php?abandonware=Virtua%20Cop%202&gid=2579))

As many probably know, light guns don't work too well with newer TV and computer monitors...if you can even connect the video of old system to the display in the first place.

[image: Nyko Light Gun for Sega Saturn and PSX]
(Image from [picclick.com](https://picclick.com/NYKO-UN80040-E09-Super%C2%A0Cobra-Light-and-Gun-Namco-Light-333110232253.html))

I have a light gun with both Sega Saturn and PSX connections. I also have a PSX to USB adapter, though I'm not sure if that will work with a PC emulator anyway because it needs a composite video connection. Thus I would settle for something similar, perhaps using one of my Wiimotes for aiming.

What are my options? Does any one know of a way to play a Sega Saturn or MAME game and configure a light gun for the PC? I'm sure it can be done, I just don't know how. Even if it's technical, it might be worth trying.